# Message doesn't go into textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Why will my values not going into my textbox. I can hard code my text but not when the value is in my list item function that's called on click.

How can I pass the value in via the `onclick` method?

**CSS**

```
.show {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <p><input type="text" name="T1" size="45" id="t" onfocus="show();" onblur="hide()"></p>
</form>

<div class="show" id="s">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="o1" onclick="c1('ss');">List 1</a></li>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function c1(vl) {
    var msg = v1;
    document.getElementById("t").value = "ddd" + msg;
    document.getElementById("s").style.display = "none";
}

function show() {
    document.getElementById("s").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("s").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Two mistakes: it’s `vl`, not `v1` (you don’t need the variable `msg`, just use `vl`) and before you can click the link the `onblur` event occurs and hides the list, before a click event can be fired.

Comment: How can I hide my div on lost focus then?

Comment: Use Jquery,makes your entire code so much easier to write and understand.Instead of writing 3 functions,using jquery,you can write a single function and call the jquery's hide() & show() methods with the div ids.Also displaying the value in the textbox can easily called using .val() method.

Comment: To hide your div on focusout, you can use `onfocusout="this.style.display='none'"` . see https://jsfiddle.net/53sns4t0/

Comment: Using jquery is a good idea. How can I create a onclick event and pass in a variable with jquery however?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small error in your js code 
You have `vl` as parameter and are assigning the value pf `v1` .
It should be :

```
function c1(vl) {
    var msg = vl;
    document.getElementById("t").value = "ddd" + msg;
    document.getElementById("s").style.display = "none";
}
```